# Распарсить JSON

Tags: json, javascript

Есть json - http://service.smscoin.com/json/bank/17682/

Как его распарсить? Мой код не сработал. Пробывал заливать его и на свой домен, но результата 0.

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://service.smscoin.com/json/bank/17682/', function(data) {
       alert(data.number); 
    });
});
```

Comment: JSON вроде не валиден.

Comment: @VladD, @ReinRaus ♦, убрал JSONResponse = [ и в конце ], но не помогло.

Comment: @ReinRaus ♦, сделал. Превратите комментарий в ответ.

Comment: @modal, готово.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приношу извинения, он валиден, но надо убрать

```
JSONResponse =
```

Comment: @ReinRaus ♦, пометил Ваш как правильный. Странно, Вы 2 часа назад написали "готово", а запостил VladD :D

Comment: Все верно, он первее прокомментировал, я по сути повторил его комментарий.

Answer (score 4):

Вы уверены, что по вашей ссылке правильный JSON? Там текст начинается с

```
JSONResponse = [ ...
```

— не лишнее ли «`JSONResponse =`»?